# Represent the common term of the sequence as minus one in polynomial degree

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

Two days ago I've found my old notebook in which I had been writing some problems from journals/books/olympiads. And also I've found that many of these problems are still unsolved, but still call crazy interest.
I've tried some of them by  myself and in some cases got something. But there are lot of problems that still a sort of mystery for me.
So, I'll start a series of posts with those problems. Where I can I'll write from where I've tooked the problem.

There is the first one:
Is it possible to represent the common term of the sequence $1,1,-1,1,1,-1,...$ in the from of
$x_n=(-1)^{P(n)}$, where $P(n)$ - is the polynomial?
With which $r,s$ where $r$ - is the number of consecutive $1$, $s$ - number of consecutive $-1$?

In my thoughts to the fisrt part of question we need to somehow construct the polynomial that will have such properties $P(3n-2)=P(3n-1)=0$ $mod$ $2$ and $P(3n)=1$ $mod$ $2$, or prove that such polynomial does'nt exist.

Unfortunately, I did'nt mark from where I've took this problem.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such polynomial. As you have observed, as $(-1)^2 = 1$, we only care about the value of the polynomial modulo $2$.

Observe that for any $n>0$, $x^n$ has the same parity as $x$. Hence for any polynomial $P(x) = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots +a_1x+a_0$, we can reduce it modulo $2$ to:

$$P(x) \equiv (a_n+a_{n-1}+\dots + a_1)x+a_0\equiv b_1x+b_0 \pmod 2$$

where $b_0, b_1$ are either $0$ or $1$. Now it is obvious that $P(x)$ either alternates in parity (when $b_1=1$) or is of constant parity (when $b_1=0$). Therefore there is no polynomial satisfying the condition.

Comment: Very thanks! Short and clear!