# Limit with sin function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Here([Task with combination of spectrums of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977872/task-with-combination-of-spectrums-of-matrices)) I continued to post tasks from an old notebook.
So there is the next one:

> Let $|a|\le\frac{\pi}{2}, x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $x_0=a\sin{x}, \hspace{0.2cm} x_{n+1}=a\sin{x_n}$. Compute the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_n$

The main problem here is factor $a$, that removes monotonity of the sequence in case when $a\in(1;\frac{\pi}{2})$(so we can't say that limit is zero as if the sequence is just $x_{n+1}=\sin{x_n}$ or even smaller when $a\le1$).
So, when $a\le1$, we can use the squezze map theorem:

> Let $\phi(x)=a\sin{x}$, then $|\phi'(x)|=|a\cos{x}|\le|a|\le1$ and by squezze map theorem the limit is the root of the equation $x=a\sin{x}$, so $x=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_n=0$.

So, the case when $a\in(1;\frac{\pi}{2})$ is still unsolved for me. It's obvious that if $a\in(1;\frac{\pi}{2})$, then $|x_n|\le\frac{\pi}{2}$ and from this we can see that the sequence is bounded: $x_n\in(0;\frac{\pi}{2}) \hspace{0.2cm} if \hspace{0.2cm} x<0$ and $x_n\in(-\frac{\pi}{2};0) \hspace{0.2cm} if \hspace{0.2cm} x>0$.

Any help will be appreciated!